# Traverse DOM find id backwards

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I can't find out how to solve this

```
<div>
  <p id="p1"> Price is  <span>$ 25</span></p>
  <p id='p2'> But this price is $ <span id="s1">50,23</span> </p>
  <p id='p3'> This one :  $ 14540.12 dollar</p>
</div>
```

What i'm trying to do is find an element with a price in it and it's shortest path to it.
This is what i have sofar.

```
$elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('*');

foreach($elements as $child)
{
   if (preg_match("/.$regex./",$child->nodeValue)){
      echo $child->getNodePath(). "<br />";

   }
}
```

This results in

```
/html
/html/body
/html/body/div
/html/body/div/p[1]
/html/body/div/p[1]/span
/html/body/div/p[2]
/html/body/div/p[2]/span
/html/body/div/p[3]
```

These are the paths to the elements i want, so that's OK in this test HTML. But in real webpages these path's get very long and are error prone.
What i'd like to do is find the closest element with an ID attribute and refer to that.

So once found and element that matched the $regex, I need to travel up the DOM and find the first element with and ID attribute and create the new shorter path from that. 
In the HTML example above, there are 3 prices matching the $regex. The prices are in:

```
//p[@id="p1"]/span
//p[@id="s1"]
//p[@id="p3"]
```

So that is what i'd like to have returned from my function. The means I also need to get rid of all the other paths that exist, because they don't contain $regex

Any help on this?

Comment: Should I use SimpleXML instead?

Comment: So, this would be some kind of preprocessing analysis to prepare the actual XSLT which will be applied? Interesting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use XPath to follow the ancestor-path to the first node containing an `@id` attribute and then cut its path off. Did not clean up the code, but something like this:

```
// snip
$xpath = new DomXPath($doc);
foreach($elements as $child)
{
    $textValue = '';
    foreach ($xpath->query('text()', $child) as $text)
        $textValue .= $text->nodeValue;
    if (preg_match("/.$regex./", $textValue)) {
        $path = $child->getNodePath();
        $id = $xpath->query('ancestor-or-self::*[@id][1]', $child)->item(0);
        $idpath = '';
        if ($id) {
            $idpath = $id->getNodePath();
            $path = '//'.$id->nodeName.'[@id="'.$id->attributes->getNamedItem('id')->value.'"]'.substr($path, strlen($idpath));
        }
        echo $path."\n";
   }
}
```

Printing something like

```
/html
/html/body
/html/body/div
//p[@id="p1"]
//p[@id="p1"]/span
//p[@id="p2"]
//span[@id="s1"]
//p[@id="p3"]
```

Comment: Great Jens! That worked, it indeed gives me output like above. Now I want remove the unnecessary paths. In this example I only need //p[@id="p1"]/span , //span[@id="s1"] and //p[@id="p3"].
How can I achieve this?

Comment: What are "the unnecessary paths"? Anyway, this might better fit as a new question.

Comment: Don't tink this is a new question. 
I'm looking for the shortest path to the elements containg $regex. As you can see in your answer above these paths are found

//p[@id="p1"]/span
//span[@id="s1"]
//p[@id="p3"]

So i don't need /html, /html/body etc. neither //p[@id="p1"] because the regex was found in the span below that ( see output above) 
So in my example i only need 3 lines of output, the rest is unnecessary

Comment: I still do not get how to filter the paths, I don't think you described that in your question. If I overlooked something, please highlight what I missed. I did not change anything with your regular expression, that must have been broken from the start.

Comment: Jens thanks,I've rewritten my question a bit, I hope that makes things a bit cleared.  Appriciete your help!

Comment: Maybe you should also give `$regex`.

Comment: I'm not sure about the regex yet, but it's going to match prices only.
So it only matches 25 and 50,23 and 14540.12 and the elements containing those values are what it need

Comment: You're probably looking for something like `\d+([.,]\d+)?`. I'm not totally sure what you want to do with the dots in the pattern around `$regex`.

Comment: I'm not looking for a regex, know how to do that. The regex isn't important in my example, it just matches 'something '

Comment: So if I understand you right, you only want to search the _direct text nodes_ below `$child`. You either need to loop over all children and test them or use XPath again. I added some lines before the if clause.

Comment: Great!!  That's what i needed. Thanks Jens.
I'd like to vote up your answer but i don't have the reputation to do so

Comment: You will have some time. ;) If an answer solved your problem, you should mark it as accepted. How to do this is hidden somewhere in the [FAQ]. For future questions, have a look on how to post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) – this helps limiting such extended discussions a lot.