# xpath of xmllint output

Tags: xml, xpath, xmllint

I have some xml documents that I want to do xquery operations on.  xmllint appears to almost do what I want by returning the nodes that match the query.  This does not help me since this node may exist many places and I'm left not knowing where the matches are.

A very simple example is **xmllint -xpath '//shutdown[text()="false"]'** returns: `<shutdown>false</shutdown><shutdown>false</shutdown><shutdown>false</shutdown><shutdown>false</shutdown><shutdown>false</shutdown>`.

This tells me there are matching nodes but not which nodes.  Is there some method for getting the actual xpath of the returned nodes?  I have not been able to find anything.

While the example given could also be done greping the xml document from within an editor, this approach is not possible with more complex queries.

Comment: `fn:path()` (http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-path) is what you are looking for. However, this is XQuery 3.0 and I don't think xmllint supports it. If you don't have to use this tool, BaseX and eXist are two open source XQuery 3.0 processors. `basex -q '//shutdown[text()="false"]/path()'` what do the job.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into those components.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with plain XPath 1.0 as supported by `xmllint` (which does not support XQuery as you tagged the question!). XPath 3.0 (and also XQuery 3.0) would have support for `fn:path($element)` as proposed by @dirkk. XPath 1.0 can only be used to *select* whole subtrees (including single elements, text nodes, attributes, ...), but not create new results from your XML documents.

You'll have to use a more powerful language like XQuery or anything else to further work on the XPath result of an `ancestor-or-self` axis step, which contains all elements along the path and join the element names:

An XQuery example:

```
string-join(
  (
    (: root node :)
    "",
    (: following steps :)
    for $step in //path/to/element/ancestor-or-self::*
    return name($step)
  ),
  "/"
)
```

Similar could be performed with arbitrary scripting languages, I also proposed a [PHP equivalent in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20928522/695343), additionally even using positional predicates for specific paths (this could be easily removed from the code again).

Comment: Sorry for the bad XQUERY tag, I just think of it as a query.  I'll be sure to keep it straight when talking about it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

**Content of test.xml:**

```
<l0>
<l1>
    <l1-1>
        <shutdown>true</shutdown>
    </l1-1>
    <l1-2>
        <shutdown>false</shutdown>
    </l1-2>
</l1>
<l2>
    <l2-1>
        <shutdown>false</shutdown>
    </l2-1>
</l2></l0>
```

**Shell Script:**

```
#!/bin/s

xpath="//shutdown[text()='false']"
count=$(echo "xpath ${xpath}" |xmllint --shell test.xml |grep ELEMENT|wc -l)

x=1
while [ $x -lt `expr $count + 1` ]
do
    parents=`       echo "xpath (${xpath})[${x}]/ancestor::*" | \
                    xmllint --shell test.xml| \
                    grep "ELEMENT" |\
                    sed "s/.*ELEMENT//"|\
                    sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ -> /g'`
    echo "${parents} -> shutdown(false)[${x}]"
    x=`expr $x + 1`
done
```

**Results:**

```
 l0 ->  l1 ->  l1-2 -> shutdown(false)[1]
 l0 ->  l2 ->  l2-1 -> shutdown(false)[2]
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tried this but apparently the xmllint loaded on our device does not have the --shell option.  I'll need to see if I can get it loaded with a version that has that option.

Comment: NO Problem.  Let me see if I can rewrite it without that option. But if you can ugrade, you get some nice features.

Comment: OK.. I was able to get the results you were looking for, but it was a bigger wrapper program - appending /.. each time and walking up the tree.  This was cumbersome and ugly.  If you need to use xmllint, then I think you need the version that has the shell built in.  Also, keep in mind that there are other command-line XML tools that may gove what you want in an easier way.